# Run a Python server in Azure websites enviroment

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

You can run a [node server](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-%28mac%29/) in Azure Websites based on the documentation of Azure.

Is it possible to run stand alone Python server script ie. cherryPy and have IIS to redirect request to the server?

Comment: You can run python scripts, there's an SDK. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/ I don't know what you mean about IIS to redirect request to server. Which server? Or do you mean the script?

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can run python scripts in Windows Azure WebSites. [You can read more here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/).

From the referred page:

> Note: Windows Azure web sites now come with Python 2.7 and wfastcgi
>   handler pre-installed. However, web frameworks such as Django are not
>   included. You can still use a different Python interpreter if you
>   prefer. You just need to include it in the Git repository and
>   configure the web site to use that interpreter instead of the Python
>   2.7 interpreter already installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to run Python in Windows Azure Web Sites. The only supported platforms at present are .NET, Node.js and PHP.

You can run Python sites in Cloud Services. See [this tutorial on deploying a Django application](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/django-with-visual-studio/) for more info.

Comment: Not used it, but surely this is python on azure websites? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/